# How to disable radiogroup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-group, disabled-control

I am doing an application in asp.net mvc. I have a radiobuttongroup to be set as Yes always and I want to disable it. This is my radiobutton group..

```
@Html.RadioButton("rdoGp_PriTenant", "rdoGp_PriTenantYes", true)<label>Yes</label>
@Html.RadioButton("rdoGp_PriTenant", "rdoGp_PriTenantNo", false)<label>No</label>
```

I tried

```
document.getElementById("rdoGp_PriTenant").disabled = true;
```

But it didnt work.Can anyone pls help..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look in MSDN: [InputExtensions.RadioButton Method (HtmlHelper, String, Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd492690%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

There is a constructor:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButton(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    Object value,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

You have property `htmlAttributes`, where you could put your advanced HTML attributes (for example `new { disabled = "disabled" }`):

```
@Html.RadioButton("rdoGp_PriTenant", "rdoGp_PriTenantYes", true, new { disabled = "disabled" })<label>Yes</label>
@Html.RadioButton("rdoGp_PriTenant", "rdoGp_PriTenantNo", true, new { disabled = "disabled" })<label>No</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use

```
 $("#rdoGp_PriTenant")
```

it selects only the first element with the given ID.

However, when you select by attribute (e.g. id in your case), it returns all matching elements, like so:

```
 $("[id=rdoGp_PriTenant]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Working code using Jquery would be:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $("[id=rdoGp_PriTenant]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    });
</script>
```